# Multiple DIVs as json string into localStorage

Tags: jquery, json, local-storage

I have got html with a few (may be more than 2) similar DIVs:

```
<div class="article">
<img id="img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/IBM_logo.svg/400px-IBM_logo.svg.png" />
<div class="text2ls">IBM</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="article">
<img id="img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Microsoft_logo_%282012%29.svg/440px-Microsoft_logo_%282012%29.svg.png" />
<div class="text2ls">Microsoft</div>
</div>
```

And want to add them into localStorage as JSON strings. This is my jQuery:

```
$('.article').each(function () {
var imageUrl = $(this).find('img[id=img]').attr('src');
convertImgToBase64(imageUrl, function (base64Img) {
    localStorage.setItem('elephant', base64Img);
    var picture = localStorage.getItem('elephant');
    lsengine(picture);
});
});
function lsengine(pic) {
var copy = $('.text2ls').html();
var article = {
    "text": copy,
        "image": pic
};
localStorage.setItem('articles', JSON.stringify(article));
localStorage.removeItem('elephant');
}
```

But for some reasons it adds the content of only one DIV. Would you please help me what I am doing wrong?

Please play with my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5eq3koco/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `localStorage.setItem('articles', JSON.stringify(article));` on every iteration of the `$.each` loop. What you can do is having a global array to store each article object and stringify it after the loop is over. Something similar to this:

```
var articles = [];
$('.article').each(function () {
    var imageUrl = $(this).find('img[id=img]').attr('src');
    convertImgToBase64(imageUrl, function (base64Img) {
        localStorage.setItem('elephant', base64Img);
        var picture = localStorage.getItem('elephant');
        lsengine(picture);
    });
});
function lsengine(pic) {
    var copy = $('.text2ls').html();
    articles.push({
        "text": copy,
        "image": pic
    });
}

localStorage.setItem('articles', JSON.stringify(articles));
localStorage.removeItem('elephant');
```

**EDIT** The second problem you have with your fiddle demonstration is that the stringify function happens immediately where as your img.onload which triggers your writing to localStorage happens asynchronously. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/limdauto/5eq3koco/8/

Comment: Thank you @LimH but it doesn't help unfortunately.

Please have a look at jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/5eq3koco/6/

Comment: @qqruza I have updated the fiddle with a bit more tweaks. My answer addressed the fundamental problem. The fiddle isn't working because of the way it's set up.